# SSIS OnVariableValueChanged not fired

Tags: ssis, event-handling, biml

I am generating a SSIS dtsx using BIML.
I want every change of a value of any variable to be logged.
I have several variables, all with RaiseChangeEvent at TRUE.
I have a OnVariableValueChanged event handler set for the package and for the dataflow where the variables are changed (by a Count Row).

When I execute the dtsx I see the handler is not even called.
I tried with other events and they are called.
So what is preventing the OnVariableValueChanged to be handled?

All the variables will be set to 0 or positive values and I made sure they start with a value of -1 in order to be sure there will actually be a change of value.

Comment: I also read this: https://munishbansal.wordpress.com/2009/02/04/onvariablevaluechanged-event-handler-in-ssis-package/

I have a handler at package level, one on dataflow and one on each of the sql script in the control flow.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me. I create a variable with `RaiseChangedEvent` set to true. I then have a For Loop increment that value. I have a script task inside the for loop logging the value and an Event Handler attached to the package for the OnVariableValueChanged event. There I have a sequence container and a script task (disabled). If I put a breakpoint on the container, I can see that it is being called. Enabling the script task there, despite being the same code as in the control flow, results in a timeout error for locking the variable. /shrug

```
<!-- http://stackoverflow.com/q/42945383/181965 -->
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Packages>
        <Package Name="so_42945383" >
            <Variables>
                <Variable DataType="Int32" Name="IndexCurrent" RaiseChangedEvent="true">-1</Variable>
                <Variable DataType="Int32" Name="IndexStart">0</Variable>
                <Variable DataType="Int32" Name="IndexStop">1</Variable>
            </Variables>
            <Tasks>
                <ForLoop Name="FLT Modify values" ConstraintMode="Linear">
                    <InitializerExpression><![CDATA[@[User::IndexCurrent] = @[User::IndexStart]]]></InitializerExpression>
                    <LoopTestExpression><![CDATA[@[User::IndexCurrent] <= @[User::IndexStop]]]></LoopTestExpression>
                    <CountingExpression><![CDATA[@[User::IndexCurrent] = @[User::IndexCurrent] + 1]]></CountingExpression>
                    <Tasks>
                        <Container Name="SEQC Do nothing" />
                        <Script ProjectCoreName="FLT_ST_EchoBack" Name="SCR Echo Back FLT">
                            <ScriptTaskProjectReference ScriptTaskProjectName="ST_EchoBack" />
                        </Script>  
                    </Tasks>
                </ForLoop>
            </Tasks>
            <Events>
                <Event Name="OVVC" EventType="OnVariableValueChanged">
                    <Tasks>
                        <Container Name="SEQC Do nothing" />
                        <Script ProjectCoreName="OVCC_ST_EchoBack" Name="SCR Echo Back OVVC" Disabled="true">
                            <ScriptTaskProjectReference ScriptTaskProjectName="ST_EchoBack" />
                        </Script>  
                    </Tasks>
                </Event>
            </Events>
        </Package>
    </Packages>
<ScriptProjects>
        <ScriptTaskProject ProjectCoreName="ST_EchoBack" Name="ST_EchoBack" VstaMajorVersion="0">
            <ReadOnlyVariables>
                <!-- List all the variables you are interested in tracking -->
                <Variable Namespace="User" VariableName="IndexCurrent" DataType="Int32" />
                <Variable Namespace="User" VariableName="IndexStart" DataType="Int32" />
                <Variable Namespace="User" VariableName="IndexStop" DataType="Int32" />
            </ReadOnlyVariables>
            <Files>
                <File Path="ScriptMain.cs" BuildAction="Compile">using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ST_EchoBack
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        public void Main()
        {
            bool fireAgain = false;
            string message = "{0}::{1} : {2}";
            foreach (var item in Dts.Variables)
            {
                Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "SCR Echo Back", string.Format(message, item.Namespace, item.Name, item.Value), string.Empty, 0, ref fireAgain);
            }

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }

        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
    }
}                </File>
                <File Path="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" BuildAction="Compile">
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
                </File>
            </Files>
            <AssemblyReferences>
                <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System" />
                <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System.Data" />
                <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System.Windows.Forms" />
                <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System.Xml" />
                <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll" />
                <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="Microsoft.SqlServer.ScriptTask.dll" />
            </AssemblyReferences>
        </ScriptTaskProject>
    </ScriptProjects>
</Biml>
```